# How do I write a function calculate a running average of time stamp for an unbound dataset in python?

Tags: python

using vanilla python (regular loops and basic data structures i.e. no pandas, numpy) how do I calculate a running average of elapsed time.

Here is an example of the data. Where left to right the values are session,step,timestamp. there are only 4 finite steps. But there can be a never ending stream of records.

```
[
      ('1000', '1', '100'),
      ('1000', '2', '102'),
      ('1000', '3', '104'),
      ('1000', '4', '106'),
      ('1001', '1', '107'),
      ('1001', '2', '109'),
      ('1001', '3', '115'),
      ('1001', '4', '118')
      ]
```

If I want to know the average elapsed time of each step how would I do that. Note that I will not have all the data at once. the data is unbound. So I will need to keep computing the running average every time I run the function.

So each time I get data like this

```
[
  ('1000', '1', '100')
]
```

Then the next time I might get

```
[
  ('1000', '2', '102'),
  ('1000', '3', '104'),
]
```

I want a function to return a dictionary where the step is the key and the average is the value. And each time I run the average is updated i.e. I need to keep state.Assume the data is unbound i.e. it has no end.

Edit: To clarify. We wouldn't see all the data at once. We would see the data in small chunks where the Len(list)>=1:

Example:

```
Input: [
  (1000, 1, 100)
]
Output:
{1:0,2:0,3:0}.
```

Since we do not have the timestamp of step2. Only step 1.

Then we get a 2 tuples in the list for steps 2 and 3 in session 1000.
Input:

```
[
  (1000, 2, 102),
  (1000, 3, 104),
]
```

Output:

```
{1:2,2:0,3:0}
```

This is because we get step 2 in session 1000. We know step 1 took 2 seconds and there is only 1 instance of step 1. So avg is 1.

If we get the following tuples in the next few streams:

```
 [(1000, 4, 106),
      (1001, 1, 107),
      (1001, 2, 109),
      (1001, 3, 115),
      (1001, 4, 118)
]
```

Then the output returned should be :

```
{1:2,2:4,3:2.5}
```

Just to make it clear that this is a running average let's assume we get two more streams:

```
[(1000, 1, 120),
      (1000, 2, 130)
]
Output would be
{1:4.67,2:4,3:2.5}
```

1 gets updated to 4.67 because the running total is 14. And it's showed up 3 times. so 14/3.

Hope that clarifies it. If it helps, maybe even think of each stream just containing one tuple instead of a list of an arbitrary number of tuples. I just want to understand the concept of how to preserve state and to keep a running average going.

Comment: Running average forever?  Or running average over the last N samples?

Comment: Show us what the output would be for your 8 sample lines.

Comment: Ok I'll update the post. But I'll answer here as well. The key point is we wouldn't see all the data at one. So the first time we get [
  ('1000', '1', '100')
] The next time we get [
  ('1000', '2', '102'),
  ('1000', '3', '104'),
] so now we can calculate the avg for step1 which is 102- 100 = 2. We divide that by 1 because we only have one instance of step 1 so far.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: @TimRoberts Running average forever. Added more context to post.

Answer (score 0):

You could deal with format of your record, I will talk about some generic function next() which returns next value or throw exception for exit

```
mean = 0.0
k    = 0
while True:
    v = next()
    k = k + 1
    
    mean = (mean*(k-1) + v)/k
```

Logic is simple - assume you have all previous k-1 values equal to mean, sum of them being (k-1)*mean, add next value for new sum and divide by number of items processed for new mean